# Is there a shortcut to change snapping type?

Tags: interface, shortcut, snapping

I really like the "Pie-menus" addon, it allows me to change my editing setting *really* quickly. It's awesome. 
I also love snapping, it's so snappy and fun, but I need a better way to change the snapping type (i.e. vertex, increment, or face) than this:

[image: Gif not uploading?!?!?!]

I think a hotkey for toggling snapping type and pie menus would work great together, in fact, it's probably already a thing. So what is the key shortcut?

Comment: shift+tab to toggle snap

Comment: @WhovianBron3 that toggles *snap* i'm looking for snap type. but thanks bro.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. In addition, you can also toggle snapping altogether from there.

---

You could literally have hovered over it :P

Comment: @lemon It was! :P

Comment: @someonewithpc wait, i lied. hovering does work. iḿ just a midless filth.

Comment: **You can accept this answer in two minutes** you too fast for the system...

Answer (score 0):

Set up theses shortcuts under “3D View (Global)”:

[image: shortcuts 1]
[image: shortcuts 2]

- Shortcut: wm.context_toggle_enum
- Context: tool_settings.snap_element
- Value: INCREMENT, VERTEX, EDGE, FACE, and VOLUME