# Translation snapping toggle - Specific dynamic snapping

Tags: interface, workflow, customization, shortcut, snapping

*[This is 1 question explained in several questions]*

*(And as notice asking several questions in separate threads is limited to 40 minutes)*

---

**Can you change the snapping target and element while snapping.**

**Or can you dynamically change the snapping target and element while snapping?**

---

-)
Also know about toggling the snapping in general:

[Is there a shortcut to change snapping type?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57403/is-there-a-shortcut-to-change-snapping-type)

This is not what I mean.

-)
I know about the [ctrl] snapping feature. When translating an object you can toggle the snapping on and off. This is fine by itself but more specific toggle would be appreciated.

*Can this method be used with specified snapping hotkeys:*

---

Can this method be used with specified snapping hotkeys:

- translate an object and toggle snap to 'closet' snapping option on or off?
- translate an object and toggle snap to 'center' snapping option on or off?
- translate an object and toggle snap to 'active' snapping option on or off?
- translate an object and toggle snap to 'median' snapping option on or off?

---

- translate an object and toggle between snap to 'edge' and snap to 'vertext' snapping options?
- translate an object and toggle between snap to 'face' and snap to 'vertext' snapping options?
- translate an object and toggle between snap to 'face' and snap to 'volume' snapping options?

---

Couldn't bind

- wm.context_toggle

with

- scene.tool_settings.snap_element

or

- bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.snap_element='VERTEX'

or

- toolsettings.snap_element

or

-bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.snap_target = 'CLOSEST'

or

...something similar

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much that you can't change targets while snapping, its more that generally if you are snapping that usually means you are using some sort of  transform operator already.

Now transform operators are generally *Modal* operators, so that means while they run there is generally a predefined set of actions you can preform, limited by what Blender developers coded into that operator.

As far as I know you could not invoke `wm.context_toggle` while an operator is already running.

That being said some of the operators do provide some snapping options you can configure. Just go to *File > User Preferences > Input* search for a transform operator like *Translate* if you expand it you can control its specific sub-keymap, which includes some basic snapping options like *Invert* or toggling on and off.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input.

With the method mentioned some limited enhanced functionalities are possible. By assigning multiple translate hot keys with snapping option and specific target selected.

It's not the perfect solution (no toggle possible). It is a limited solution which is better than nothing.

(Although it seems with the translate and possibility with toggling the snapping the more specific snapping options would not seem too far away and might be possible with some (coding) additions/adjustments.)

Comment: If an answer helped you please consider upvoting, or if it solved your problem in a satisfying manner mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: (Where some solutions are really helpful, some are not but might give answer to the possibility. Or the answer is not a total solution but it is a good help in the direction. 

Yours can be marked as the last type of answer.

*Upvoted (, although it would be more fitting if half or 0.75/75% vote was possible. Vote has been noted but is not show because of my fresh reputation)